# how to close pop-up explorer massage box?

Tags: vba, web-scraping, messagebox

I'm using VBA to learn programming.

In the process of scraping web pages with createobjct function, I am seriously stuck with problems with the following message box.

I can't go forward with VBA without closing below box. Contents of message is simple, there is no data in that page. (It is EC site)

[image: Message box from internet explorer]

```
    ...
    ie.Navigate strURL
    ie.Visible = False


    'Waiting with do while 
    Do While (ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or ie.Busy = True)
       DoEvents
    Loop

   '2seconds wait more
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")) ' Here is the stop point with message box.
```

Is there a way to close the popup message box?